# Using a mock location provider in an espresso test on Android 11+

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-11, mock-location

My Android app uses the position provided by the gps.
One of my classes overrides the `onProviderDisabled` method of LocationListener.
The app is working fine and gets the gps position.

I have an Espresso test that create a test provider for mock locations in the @Before setup() method of my test class:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.addTestProvider(LOCATION_PROVIDER_NAME, false,
                                false, false, false,
                                true, true, true,
                                POWER_USAGE_HIGH, 
                                ProviderProperties.ACCURACY_FINE);
locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(LOCATION_PROVIDER_NAME, false);
```

Then in my test, I call

```
locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(LOCATION_PROVIDER_NAME, true);
SystemClock.sleep(200);
...
test if gps is enabled
...
```

On an Android 8 device, this code works fine (`onProviderDisabled` not called)

But on Android 11, 12 and 13 devices, about 300 ms after enabling the test provider, the `onProviderDisabled` is called.

What do I need to do to enable mock location on new Android devices?

Comment: I just got a Android 11 device. Same issue as with 12 and 13. So I updated the title and the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. It is so easy when you know it !
On recent Android devices, when using mock locations in Espresso test, you must switch ON the location service manually before running the test.

Note: this was not required on Android 8 devices